# React JS Application links throwing Error 404 on live server but working on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, digital-ocean

I have this react js app build with create-react-app. I use react-router-dom for the routings. When I visit any link directly e.g url/products it will throw 404 error page. but if I go the that page from the link on the app, it will work directly. But both ways are working perfectly in development. I only get this error on production.

It is hosted on DigitalOcean

[image: 404 Error Page Showing]
This is my app.js settings:

```
<Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={Home} />
        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/products`} component={Products} />
        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/category/:category`} component={Category} />
```

Kindly help look at what I am doing wrong and suggestion for a fix

Comment: Do you have a `proxy` set in `package.json`?

Comment: No. I didn't set proxy

Comment: Use relative path instead of providing a `PUBLIC_URL` - reason is that `react-router-dom` uses `localhost` as its base and so everything you pass as `path` is relative to that. If you're in production, react will update its base url with your public url

Comment: like this? `<Route exact path="/products" component={Products} />`

Comment: Exactly. If it solved your problem, I'll turn this comment into an answer so you can accept and close the question

Comment: It's not related to the question but I feel like I should mention that if you were to provide a `proxy`, that would be the base url in react in which case you should set a `PUBLIC_URL` to change that, if you're not trying to call the api endpoint

Comment: I only set `"homepage"` in `package.json`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238311/discussion-between-olusanya-michael-and-kmp).

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. The problem still persist even after removing homepage and using a relative path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router fails on Digital Ocean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53015953/react-router-fails-on-digital-ocean)

Answer (score 5):

I am able to fix this. The issue is not with React. It is with DigitalOcean.

I have to set catchall at APP SPEC by doing this

Using Cloud panel UI:
Log in and click on App > Settings >> click on component name > scroll down to Custom page > Edit Custom page and select Catchall > Enter index.html in the page name block > Save

Answer (score 0):

Add a web.config file with following code-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in DigitalOcean server with `react` and `vite`.

#### Instal on Digital Ocean

- Create a New App on Digital Ocean, make sure that's is an `static site`.
- When you site it working correctly, test if works on with sub-routes like [www.yourweb.com/subrute](http://www.yourweb.com/subrute)

##### Last step: solve the App reloading leads to 404 site

- Download current app spec from https://cloud.digitalocean.com/apps, in the settings tab you will find App Spec to `yourappname.yaml` file
- Add `catchall_document: index.html`
- Test if works on with routes like [www.yourweb.com/subrute](http://www.yourweb.com/subrute)
- if not: Using Cloud panel UI: Log in and click on App > Settings >> click on component name > scroll down to Custom page > Edit Custom page and select Catchall > Enter index.html in the page name block > Save

> Example in `Next`: Next.js has a setting that worked for me: in
> `next.config.js`, set trailingSlashes: true. This generates the static
> page layout as /subpage/index.html, which can then be served at
> /subpage.

Source: [APP Platform: App reloading leads to 404 site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/app-platform-app-reloading-leads-to-404-site)

I hope, it will serve as a guide to someone who can find a general solution.